# Android create album art cache when music player starts

Tags: android

How can I create android album art cache file in:

`sdcard/android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumart`

When my music player opens and if the album art does not exist in that folder, example if folder deleted by user....

Answer (score 1):

use this code to get Album Art from mediaplayer.

```
 public Bitmap getAlbumart(Long album_id) 
       {
            Bitmap bm = null;
            try 
            {
                final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                    .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

                Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);

                ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver()
                    .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

                if (pfd != null) 
                {
                    FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return bm;
    }
```

you can keep this bitmaps in a folder as your app cache